# C++ condesing this code

Tags: c++

Ok so I've already simplified/condense it while keeping the functionality,but im only doing C++ for a month and a half.Was at 100 lines of code.Is it possible to declare the variable in the functions arguement and then call them without passing values into the arguemnets?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;


int primeCheck10 (int j)
{
    int count=0;
    cout<<"Enter a number between 1 and 10___";
    cin>>j;

    if(j<1 ||j>10)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid Value\n";
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i=2; i<j; i++)
    {
        if(j%i==0)
        {
         count++;
         break;
        }
    }
    if(count==0)
        cout<<"Prime number\n";
    else
        cout<<"Not a Prime number\n"; 
}
int primeCheck100(int j)
{
int count=0;
cout<<"Enter a number between 1 and 100___";
    cin>>j;

    if(j<1 || j>100){
        cout<<"Invalid Value\n";
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i=2; i<j; i++)
    {
        if(j%i==0)
        {
         count++;
         break;
        }
    }
    if(count==0)
        cout<<"Prime number\n";
    else
        cout<<"Not a Prime number\n";
}
int checkPrime1000(int j)
{
int count=0;
cout<<"Enter a number between 1 and 1000___";
    cin>>j;
    if(j<1 || j>1000){
        cout<<"Invalid Value\n";
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i=2; i<j; i++)
    {
        if(j%i==0)
        {
         count++;
         break;
        }
    }
    if(count==0)
        cout<<"Prime number\n";
    else
        cout<<"Not a Prime number\n"; 
}

int main ()
{
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have 3 different functions that do essentially the same thing. Your `checkPrime1000` function basically contains the other two.

Comment: There are more clever algorithms for [prime numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)

Comment: Some remarks: you should only loop up to i < j/2 (shaves 50% off your execution time ) and you have 3 functions that are really identical, with a parameter that you don't really use.  Change it to int `void checkPrime(int limit)`, use the limit where you have hardcoded limits right now, declare `int j;` as a local variable (makes sense as it's only used locally) and you're all set.  Net gains: 50% runtime and 66% code.

Comment: It is the code given to me in college..Ok will try.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can condense all the prime checking into a single function pretty easily. I'd change the structure of the code to *just* check whether a given number is prime, and return a `bool` to indicate whether it is or not:'

```
bool isprime(int n) {
    int limit = sqrt(n)+1;   // only need to check up to sqrt(n)

    if (n == 2)
        return true;
    if (n == 1 || n % 2 == 0)  // check if it's 1 or even
        return false;
    for (int i = 3; i <= limit; i += 2) // not even -- only check odd numbers
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Then the code to get input and display results would be separate:

```
void primecheck(int limit) {
    std::cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and " << limit;
    int j;
    std::cin >> j;
    if (j<1 || j > limit) 
        std::cerr << "Invalid value";
    static char const *labels [] = { "Not a prime number\n", "Prime number\n" };
    std::cout << labels[isprime(j)];
}
```

It wouldn't be terribly difficult to make it even shorter than this, but we're reaching the point where it would probably end up less readable if you did so.

Comment: You're missing the point of the code.. its to count the amount of un permutated set of numbers of divisibility a number could have.

Comment: @progenhard: That may have been the *intent*, but it's not what the code *does*. In particular, as soon as it increments count, it also breaks out of the loop, so it only ever has count == 0 or count == 1, regardless of how many divisors a number may have.

Comment: Perfect,god dam.Wish I had more experince..
Few q's  why squre root of (n)?

Comment: @Conor: It's by no means perfect! (i) There's a missing semicolon, so it doesn't even compile. (ii) If it did compile, it would think that 2 was composite. (iii) To avoid errors due to rounding when n is the square of a prime, I would prefer limit = sqrt(n+1).

Comment: @ConorHynes: You stop at sqrt(N) because if there's a factor larger than the sqrt(N), there must also be a matching factor that's smaller than sqrt(N). If there's no factor <= sqrt(N), there there's none larger either.

Comment: @TonyK: Thanks for the proof-read (though `sqrt(N)+1` seems better than `sqrt(N+1)`, at least to me).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I suppose so, i guess i'm making assumptions he doesn't even call any of these functions in the main method. To be honest i didn't even notice the break, thanks for the info. Edited my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make one method... and add a bounds

```
int primecheck(int value, int bounds){
    int count=0;
    cout <<"Enter a number between 1 and " << bounds << "___";
    cin>>value;
    if(j<1 || value>bounds){
        cout<<"Invalid Value\n";
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i=2; i<value/2; i++)
    {
        if(value%i==0)
        {
         count++;
        }
    }
    if(count==0)
        cout<<"Prime number\n";
    else
        cout<<"Not a Prime number\n"; 
    return count;
}
```

This alg is prob not the best way to check for primes though. for instance `for(int i=2; i<j/2; i++)` in your loop with optimize it. For example `32, 6x6 = 32, 2x16 = 32, 4x8 = 32.` The highest number that can be divisible to j or value is half of it because `1` isn't considered under divisibility so the lowest number would be 2. Which is half.

Answer (score 0):

If I have unserstood correctly you then you are asking about default arguments. For example

```
#include <iostream>

void f( int i = 10 )
{
   std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
   f();
}
```

Comment: Yes,thanks for the example! Does it have to be void?